# Picking of elements of a list by subelement

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array of form

`array=[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],...]`

and I need to generate two new arrays from this, one containing all the elements which its x part is 0, and the other containing all other elements. What's the most efficient way to execute this?

Comment: Having a `numpy` array of shape `N x 3`, you can use `arr_new_x = np.copy(array); arr_new_x[:, 0] = 0` and `arr_new_y = np.copy(array); arr_new_y[:, 1] = 0`